# Remove element from List of Maps in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

I have a `List` of `Map`, each containing three key/value pairs:

```
List(
  Map("id" -> 1, "key" -> 11, "value" -> 111), 
  Map("id" -> 2, "key" -> 22, "value" -> 222), 
  Map("id" -> 3, "key" -> 33, "value" -> 333), 
  Map("id" -> 4, "key" -> 44, "value" -> 444))
```

I would like to transform this to JSON but before that I need to remove the `key` and its value from every map and rename the `value` key to `title`. How can this be done in Scala in a elegant way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A similar approach to redefining the given list of maps, which fetches values of interest (an omits the rest),

```
mapsList.map { m => Map( "id" -> m("id"), "title" -> m("value") )}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fitted my needs perfectly

Answer (score 6):

You can do this:

```
val m1 = Map("id" -> 1, "key" -> 2, "value" -> 3)
val m2 = m1 - "key"  // Map(id -> 1, value -> 3)
val m3 = m2 + ("title" -> m2("value")) - "value"
// Map(id -> 1, title -> 3)
```

So, for an entire list:

```
list.map(m => m + ("title" -> m("value")) - "value" - "key")
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you keys are `String`:

```scala
listOfMap map { m => (m - "key") + ("title" -> m("value")) - "value" }
```

That's to say for each element of the list (each `m: Map`), *1* create a copy without entry with key "key" (`m - "key"`), *2* create a second copy based on first one by appending a new entry with key "title" and value from entry with key "value" from original map `m` (`+ ("title" -> m)`), *3* and finally create finally map that will takes place in new list by removing entry for key "value" (finalizing the 'renaming': `- "value"`).

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with this

```
 val list = ... // your definition

 list map { 
   _ collect {
     case ("value", v) => "title" -> v
     case tpl @ (k, v) if k != "key" => tpl
   }
 }
```